# Python Request to Get Token

Tags: python, api, post, request

I am trying to use Request POST method to get access token.

According to their API document:

```
HTTP Request POST /api/auth

curl -X POST "/api/auth"
  -F email=my_email 
  -F api_key=my_api_key
```

from https://api.aupropertyreport.com/doc/#authentication

I wrote like this:

```py
auth_url = 'https://aupropertyreport.com/api/auth'

response = requests.post(auth_url, data = {
                        'email':'xxxxx@hotmail.com',
                        'api_key':auproperty_api,
                        })
token = response.json()
```

And it seems not working if anyone knows how to solve this?

Error Message:

```
{'err_code': '9001',
 'err_title': '\u51fa\u9519\u5566',
 'err_msg': 'success',
 'data': [],
 'has_next_page': False,
 'updated': '2022-03-15 17:58:23'}
```

If successful, it should return something like this (as an example from its API documentation):

```
{
    "data": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbHVtZd4tYXBpLWRlbW8uZGV1L2FwaS9hdXRob3JpemF0aW9ucyIsImlhdCI6MTQ4Mzk3NTY5MywiZXhwIjoxNDg5MTU5NjkzLCJuYmYiOjE0ODM5NzU2OTMsImp0aSI6ImViNzAwZDM1MGIxNzM5Y2E5ZjhhNDk4NGMzODcxMWZjIiwic3ViIjo1M30.hdny6T031vVmyWlmnd2aUr4IVM9rm2Wchxg5RX_SDpM",
        "expired_at": "2017-03-10 15:28:13",
        "refresh_expired_at": "2017-01-23 15:28:13"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. The details should go into header and not data.

```
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["email"] = "<email-id>"
headers["api_key"] = "<api_key>"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"    
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but same error code. I am guessing maybe CURL is not correct?  Under its API documentation, it only gives   curl  "/api/auth"

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
url = 'https://aupropertyreport.com/api/auth'
headers={}
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["email"] = "xxxx@hotmail.com"
headers["api_key"] = auproperty_api
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"    
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
token = response.json()

Comment: Change the content-type as below and try with that, perhaps?

Comment: thanks, I have tried it. didn't work, I think the code is correct, but the url may be wrong, its API document is a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

The CURL command shows the option `-F` which refers to form-data in POST request. However, python requests doesn't know it should send `data` as multipart/form-data.

Add a header field in your post request to use `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, but I have tried it, it still gives back the same error. I think maybe the URL is not correct.  As the API document only gives  /api/auth,    I added https://aupropertyreport.com/  in front of that. Maybe it is wrong....

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
https://api.aupropertyreport.com/doc/#authentication